# Where is the contradiction in the proof of the Uniform Time Lemma?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I really don't see what is the contradiction in the proof of the Uniform Time lemma (Lee's introduction to Smooth manifolds):

[image]

The first highlighted inequality seems to imply the second one, so I don't see how this is a contradiction. **Where is the contradiction? Moreover, why is this lemma  called "uniform time" ?**

---

Some more information if you are not familiar with this book:

-$\theta^{(p)}$ denotes an integral curve starting at the point  $p$ of the manifold

-A smooth vector field is complete if it generates a global flow, or equivalently if each of its maximal integral curves is defined for all $t \in \Bbb R$
-A maximal integral curve is one that cannot be extended to an integral curve on any larger open interval, and a maximal flow is a flow that admits no extension to a flow on a larger flow domain.

-A flow is a map $\theta_t:M\to M  : p \mapsto \theta^{(p)}(t)$, ie it maps $p$ to the point obtained by following for time $t$ the integral curve starting at $p$. More precisely:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don’t get what they’re talking about, but the contradictory part seems to lay on “$\gamma$ [being] an integral curve starting at $p$”.

Comment: @Rócherz Yes, you are right, I still don't see why is that a contradiction though, that just means $\gamma(0)=p$

Comment: The contradiction lies in the fact that $b$ is the superior of $\mathcal{D}^{(p)}$ so you can't have an integral curve defined for $t>b$ (and in your case $\gamma$ is defined up to $t_0+\varepsilon>b$)

Comment: @MatteoIaccarino I am not so sure,  $\mathscr D^{(p)}$ is the domain of $\theta^{(p)}$ which is another integral curve, while$\gamma$ is an extension as seen from its definition.

Comment: Also I don't know why we need the translation lemma to argue that $\gamma$ starts at p, if we already know from the definition that $\gamma(0)=\theta^{(p)}(0)=p$

Comment: @some_math_guy They form a single integral curve. That's the point of "The two definitions agree where they  overlap."

Comment: @AndreasBlass I think that staments is just  so that gamma is well-defined. But then just because they start at the same point, are $\gamma$ and $\theta^{(p)}$  the same curve?. Can't two integral curves start at the same point and end at different points, making them different? i cut just restrict the domain of one to make it end before the other one

Comment: @some_math_guy The two integral curves don't just agree at one point. They agree along a whole segment: The first half of $\gamma$ coincides with the last $\epsilon$ part of $\theta^{(p)}$. And that's enough to ensure that the combined curve is an integral curve.